# How to convert a sentence to have partizipal structure?

Tags: past-participle, participle

> Kombinierte Studiengänge sind ein Trend, der auf eine Entwicklung sowohl in der Wissenschaft als auch auf dem Arbeitsmarkt reagiert. (Umformulieren mit Partizip Struktur)

I am a bit confused on how to go about this question.  Here are my thoughts so far:

1. We have to first make a decision on which verb to turn into participle. It could either be "sind" or "reagiert", intuition says it should be reagieren.
2. We need to figure out where to place the participle... which I am again not sure of how to decide that.

I saw these two example formulations online [from](https://language-easy.org/de/grammatik/satzbau/partizipalsatz/):

> Gleichzeitige Handlungen- Partizip 1

> Während Philip das Fleisch brät, spielt er mit seinem Hund
>
> Das Fleisch bratend, spielt Philip mit seinem Hund

> Nachdem Philip das Fleisch gebraten hat, spielt er mit seinem Hund
>
> Das Fleisch gebraten, spielt Philip mit seinem Hund

Now, I can't figure out how to use the ideas from these two examples to solve my original one. I guess one point one can take away is where the verb should be after made into participle form. It should be nearby to where it was relative to other words before conversion.

---

Expected answer is supposed to be

> Kombinierte Studiengänge sind ein auf eine Entwicklung sowohl in der Wissenschaft als auch auf dem Arbeitsmarkt reagierender Trend.

Comment: The two exercises are unrelated. I wouldn't trust the second site at all. The first is fine, but if there is no example or answer key given, what use is it to you?

Comment: I've edited in the answer @DavidVogt

Comment: I wouldn't trust a site purporting to teach German but writing "**Umformulieren mit Partizip Struktur**". *Compound nouns* are expected to be *compounded* in German, it is "Partizipstruktur".

Comment: Overcomplicated grammatical structures can be dangerous. Don't try this at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about that language-easy site. This is wrong information, German speakers don't talk nor write like that.

---

> Kombinierte Studiengänge sind ein Trend, *der **auf eine Entwicklung sowohl in der Wissenschaft als auch auf dem Arbeitsmarkt reagiert.***

What you have there is a relative clause. Such clauses explain a noun. But you can also "inline" them as a participle group. To do that, you have to turn the conjugated verb into a Partizip I.

So the relative pronoun in dropped, *reagiert* becomes *reagierend*, it's declined for the noun, and all that is inlined before the noun.

> Kombinierte Studiengänge sind ein ***auf eine Entwicklung sowohl in der Wissenschaft als auch auf dem Arbeitsmarkt reagierender*** Trend.

---

For example in Perfekt there is an auxiliary, so you have to make that conjugated auxiliary the Partizip I instead:

> Kombinierte Studiengänge sind ein Trend, *der **auf eine Entwicklung sowohl in der Wissenschaft als auch auf dem Arbeitsmarkt reagiert hat.***

> Kombinierte Studiengänge sind ein ***auf eine Entwicklung sowohl in der Wissenschaft als auch auf dem Arbeitsmarkt reagiert habender*** Trend.

---

The Partizip II is used if the relative clause is in passive voice. But careful, this is only possible if the action has been completed as the Partizip II is both passive **and** perfect.

> Er mag die Wurst, *die **auf das Brot gelegt worden ist.***

> Er mag die ***auf das Brot gelegte*** Wurst.